# global variable gets hoisted when passing an array

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am sorry if there is a similar answer out their somewhere. All of the hoisting answers didn't seem to quite answer my question. I have a global variable that only seems to get "hoisted" (which I don't fully understand)
when I pass an array into the function. I don't see why this changes anything.

```
var i = 0 //counter for show pattern


//this first function works fine. the console.log shows i = 0
 function myLoop () {           
    console.log("My loop:" + i);
    setTimeout(function () {    
       alert('hello');          
       i++;                     
       if (i < 3) {            
          myLoop();             
       }                        
    }, 3000)
 }

//this second function shows i as undefined. If I remove list, then the console logs i as 0 which is correct

function showPattern(list){
    console.log(list[0] + i);
    setTimeout(function(){      
        console.log("IT works!");
        //for each square on the screen
        $(".square").each(function(j,obj){
            console.log($(obj).attr("id") + "/" + list[i]);
            //if the ID is equal to the pattern number
            if(parseInt($(obj).attr("id")) === parseInt(list[i])){

                $(obj).css("opacity","1");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(obj).css("opacity",".5");
                }, 500);
            }
        })
        i++;
        if( i < list.length){
            showPattern();
        }

    },3000);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With hoisting, only the declaration part of the statement `var i = 0` (`var i`) gets hoisted. The `i = 0` part does not. So, when your code (without `list`) runs and encounters:

```
list[i]
```

`i` is undefined. However, when you pass `list` and then hit the line:

```
list[0] + i
```

The `+` symbol implicitly converts `i` to a default type that is compatible with `list[0]` (string or number).

Comment: I am sorry if my code is confusing, I was trying to do some manual debugging. The list[0] doesn't seem to matter. I can get rid of it and console.log(i) and I still get undefined. I will update my code to reflect that

Comment: Ope nevermind. I thought I had tried it differently, looks like my .log broke it... well sorry thanks

Comment: "i" has been assigned at each function when this is called. The problems are caused by accessing nonexistent lists, not with hoisting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the hoisting of "var i" is your problem at all. The second function is going to break (when you don't pass in an array) because you try to reference list[0] in your console log. You are trying to access index 0 of an array that doesn't exist. If there is no array passed in, this throws an error.

This bit of code will have that problem as well:

```
if( i < list.length){
    showPattern();
}
```